# java pair equivalent to c++

Tags: java, c++

I'm translating some code from standard C++ to Java.  Several places utilize

```
std::pair<T1,T2>
```

more specifically

```
std::pair<Date,double>
```

Is there a standard idiomatic way to express a parameterized pair type in Java?  As one example, I'm having to use a custom type

```
class Observation {
   LocalDate date;
   double value;
}
```

I have other cases as well where two or three things need to be returned from a function. In other languages, I would likely use pairs, triples, and other tuple entities.

I do not really mind making the needed little classes, but would like to know if I'm somewhere missing out on a Java feature.

Thanks in advance for your comments.

(P.S. I'm pretty sure that this is my first question ever posed on S.O.)

Comment: Thanks.  I do believe that somehow I missed that question, and it is definitely the same question.  That said, I disagree with that answer that making little classes rather than semantics-hiding pair or other tuples is a good thing. Still, thank you very much and it does totally and correctly answer my question.

Comment: Java very deliberately leaves this out.  The point is for you to make a proper class with usefully named fields.

Comment: I understand the intention of the Java designers to force me to make a class with two named fields, and that when in Rome, one should do as the Romans do.  I just wanted to ensure that I was in fact doing as the Romans do.   I disagree with that deliberate forcing and if it were to be correct, one must agree that those from outside Rome, for instance C++, Go, Scheme, Scala, Haskell, and Python programmers, much be following a poor language design decision when utilizing pairs or tuples.  Given that Java has now lambdas, I won't be surprised to see tuples one day.

Comment: No, that doesn't follow. What's a good choice for one language doesn't have to be a good choice for others. Pairs may be appropriate for one language but not another.  (And the Java leadership still seems *actively* opposed to pairs.)

Comment: @LouisWasserman Really?  I miss how unnamed structures are reasonable in one but not another.  Maybe it's the Rome thing, really.  When in C++, I -feel- as though the std::pair<T1,T2> works just fine in localized use, just as it feels okay in Python.  I'm not being coy, even if it sounded a bit, I just don't see that unnamed structures are inherently less valid than named ones.  Of course, it's moot, because that's not what Java does.  Anyway, it looks as though I'm causing a slightly inappropriate discussion, so I'll sign off.  Thanks for the comments very much.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing in the standard Java API, but various third-party libraries have pair implementations.  For example. [this one](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/tuple/Pair.html) in Apache Commons Lang.

Comment: Thanks very much as well.  This is a viable thing as well as simply implementing a simple pair class myself, but I'll just be doing the standard Java "make a little class" instead of having a dependency.